# youcompleteme can not complete sigaction struct correctly

Tags: c, linux, vim, youcompleteme

[image: sigaction completion]

As you can see above, youcompleteme can not correctly complete sigaction struct which may have the following members(Of course I know that the sa_restorer element is obsolete and should not be used):

[image: sigaction members]

So, is there anything wrong with my youcompleteme? How to make it work correctly?

Note:What I really want to ask is why can't youcompleteme show me more members of sigaction like sa_hander for me but just sa_restorer,sa_mask and sa_flags.

Comment: The `sa_restorer`  field is obsolete and unspecified. Your `youcompleteme` is correct in not showing it

Comment: I konw that, I just want to know why my youcompletemy can't work correctly

Comment: It is working correctly and cleverly. It should not show `sa_restorer` because you are not allowed to use it.

Comment: Want some help on $PLUGIN? Use $PLUGIN's issue tracker.

Comment: I'm noticing the generation gap. I am old enough (58) to have worked without fancy autocompletion, and I am on the contrary excited by what current autocompleters can achieve in practice. In some ways, your generation is "spoiled" - don't take that personally - by the great tools available. You are right to want even more of them, but then you should **contribute to free software** tools (and work on improving them, or pay someone to do that).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, good advice and tip, I'm sorry for that.

Comment: Fill free to accept or upvote my answer if it fits.

Comment: @cong: Please tell me when (and if) you work on improving YouCompleteMe.

Comment: I may try to get rid of YouCompleteMe later, trying to become a great coder is what I'm going to do, I appreciate it that you have taught me a lesson, thanks again.

Comment: @romainl, What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that YCM has two dedicated support channels. Use them.

Answer (score 1):

Read carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) and [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html). `sa_restorer` is obsolete and you are forbidden to use it.

> How to make it work correctly?

So **YouCompleteMe is *correct*** (and clever!) **in not showing it**.

<sup>(your question should be: "How is YouCompleteMe clever enough to hide `sa_restorer`?")</sup>

The more interesting question is why it does not show it while `sa_restorer` apparently appear in e.g. `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sigaction.h`, but this is a different question (and I don't know its answer). I won't be surprised if youcompleteme handed *specifically* standard functions (e.g. has some configuration files about them). BTW [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) or [open source](https://opensource.org/) so you can **study its source code**.

The type of `sa_restorer` is `__sigrestore_t` (see `/usr/include/asm-generic/signal.h`) and identifiers starting with underscores are reserved to the implementation and should not be used by user code so YouCompleteMe is perhaps skipping such fields or data. This is only a guess. Please check *YouCompleteMe* source code yourself (and perhaps also the code of other tools, such as `libclang`, used by it).

> What I really want to ask is why can't youcompleteme show me more members of sigaction like sa_handler

On my Linux system, `sa_handler` is a macro, since `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sigaction.h` (internally included from `<signal.h>`) contains:

```
 # define sa_handler    __sigaction_handler.sa_handler
```

I won't be surprised if YouCompleteMe don't bother showing all macros in completion menus. There are too many of them! This (only a guess) might explain why `sa_handler` is not explicitly proposed for completion.

<sup>(perhaps if you type `siga.sa_` the completer could be more wise and *propose* `sa_handler`  but I did not try)</sup>

Your `struct sigaction` is only what the *documentation* tells. The actual implementation is more complex. Study it if you want to understand then improve the behavior of YouCompleteMe. **Propose a patch** (by working on it a few weeks or months) **to *YouCompleteMe*** to improve its behavior.

Your future patch on YouCompleteMe might handle specifically identifiers starting with underscores and preprocessor macros using them. That is an interesting project, but could take you a few months.

Comment: I mean why can't youcompleteme show me the sa_handler or sa_flags or other members for me?

Comment: That is a different question. I would ask it to the developers of YouCompleteMe, perhaps by filling a bug request. BTW on my Linux `sa_handler` is a `#define`-d macro.

Comment: So, you mean it's a unsolvable issue?

Comment: With enough efforts, it is solvable. Are you willing to spend months of your time to work on some YouCompleteMe improvement? If yes, please do it, that is how free software works.

Comment: BTW, I won't be surprised if autocompletion happens to be related to the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) but I did not thought of that.